# Reduce ads privilege is not shown on some sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, advertising, help-center

On some sites of network page "Reduce Ads" is not shown on the list (~/help/privileges) page. Also page with privilege (~/help/privileges/reduced-ads) is absent and redirects me to privilege list (~/help/privileges) page. Also you can't track this privilege in user profile.

But privilege is working when site has ads. If you get 200 reputation on such sites you'll get reduced ads.

---

### List of [technology](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday) sites with issue (where site have ads and no "Reduce Ads" privilege)

- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

### List of [technology](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday) sites without ads and privilege

- [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Craft CMS](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [CiviCRM](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- etc

### List of [technology](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday) sites with privilege and ads

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/privileges)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges)
- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

---

So sites in first list should be tweaked either

- to remove ads at all and look like second list
- or add this privilege to be like ones in third list.

Comment: We already had [same issue](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3920/176217) on ruSO. Seems it should be fixed on each site separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've gone through and turned that privilege on for all sites where we show display ads from DFP. Thanks for bringing it up, I'll make sure that the privilege is double-checked as part of the process for enabling ads on new sites in the future.